# (Python 2.7) Data validation using try not working as expected

Tags: python, validation

I've asked a user to input a string in the format "AB12 XYZ" using raw_input. The code below is supposed to validate that the string follows this format, by checking that I can use str and int in the places I would expect to be able to - not an elegant solution, I'm aware, but the only one I can currently think of. If the input does not follow the expected pattern, "nonstandard" should return as true. However, currently, nonstandard is always returning as true. I suspect this may have something to do with my use of str, but I'm unsure as to exactly what.

Here's the source:

```
try:
    for x in range(0,1):
        str(Tnumberplate[x])
    global nonstandard
    nonstandard = "true"
except TypeError:
    pass
try:
    for x in range(4,6):
        str(Tnumberplate[x])
    nonstandard = "true"
except TypeError:
    pass
```

Comment: You'd better use `True` and `False` instead of strings.

Comment: Also why do you think `str(<anything>)` would throw a `TypeError` ? It shouldn't unless you have manually written a class that throws `TypeError` from `__str__()` function.

Comment: @ForceBru That's probably true, but I don't actually know how  - my knowledge of python, as you can probably tell, is very limited.

Comment: Why don't you use a regexp ??? `re.match(r"^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2} [A-Z]{3}$", "AB12 XYZ")`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers If you could explain what exactly each part of that does, I'd use it. However, I don't like using code I don't understand in my program, so right now maybe not :)

Comment: @Jay it's all documented here : https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks! That works with the rest of my program slightly better than the solution offered by Simon, so I'll be using that. Thanks!

Comment: @Jay then you may want to accept my answer instead...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I did xD. Sorry if you misunderstood my previous comment; by "that" I was referring to _your_ solution. What did you think I meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I'd point out is that numbers can be converted to valid strings, so calling `str()` on a digit will succeed.

What you could use is the `isdigit()` method:

```
>>> numberplate = 'AB12 XYZ'
>>> for character in numberplate:
...     print(character.isdigit())
... 
False
False
True
True
False
False
False
False
```

If you store this in a list you could simplify the tests:

```
expected = [False, False, True, True, False, False, False, False]
results = [character.isdigit() for character in numberplate]
if results == expected:
    # the digits are where we expect...
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's a useful bit of code I'd never come across - Should solve my problem straight off the bat. And yes, the use of str was stupid of me. I was flailing slightly :D